# KeystoneJS: How to set a field to receive randomly generated value?

Tags: random, keystonejs

I'm creating a model that I will use to authenticate users for API access, and I have a `secret` field where I want to store a `Base64` encoded `uuid/v4` generated value.

I went through the different field types and options, but still not seeing how I could achieve this.

Is there a way to hook in model instance creation, and set the value of my `secret` field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [pre hooks](https://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/methods/pre%20%22pre%20hooks:).

In your situation, the basics would be:

```
AuthenticationModel.schema.pre("save", function(next) {
  const secretValue = generateSecretValue();
  this.secret = secretValue;
  next();
});
```

That would go before your final `AuthenticationModel.register();` in your model.js file.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set it up, also with the pre-save hook. My problem before was that I was getting the same random number again until I restarted the server.

```
Store.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (!this.updateId && this.isNew) {
        // generates a random ID when the item is created
        this.updateId = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
    }
    next();
});
```

Using `this.isNew` was also useful in my case.