# Is it Possible to add custom validation like user exist using updater method in keystone js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

Is it Possible to add custom validation like  user exist using updater method in keystone js

```
updater.process(req.body, {
        flashErrors: true,
        fields: 'name, email, phone, enquiryType, message',
        errorMessage: 'There was a problem submitting your enquiry:',
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            locals.validationErrors = err.error;
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            locals.enquirySubmitted = true;
        }
        next();
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeystoneJS: How to set a field to receive randomly generated value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688378/keystonejs-how-to-set-a-field-to-receive-randomly-generated-value)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `pre` hooks.

The documentation is here: https://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/methods/pre

Related question: [KeystoneJS: How to set a field to receive randomly generated value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688378/keystonejs-how-to-set-a-field-to-receive-randomly-generated-value/52732027?noredirect=1#comment92422896_52732027)

Using `pre("save",` you can do whatever you would like as you can access and modify the data - accessed via `this`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your replay. I am asking how to add custom validation using updater method like check password matches with confirm password etc